# Circular Immutable Linked List in Java

Tags: java, reference, immutability

I have a simple Immutable Linked list class the following:

```
class Node<T> {
    final T val;
    final Node next;
    Node(T val, Node next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

I would like to create an instance which  has itself as the next node, thereby creating a circular list.

I obviously can't do `Node x = new Node<>(0, x)`, since `x` won't be defined by the time it should be passed to the constructor.

Are there any tricks that'd allow me to create this without changing `Node`?

For example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25473855/205521 describes how to do something similar for lambda functions, that is a function which refers to itself (recursion). I, however, wasn't able to make it work for initialization.

Comment: No. Since the field is final, not even reflection can change the field's value.

Comment: you can have a setter for the next Node and set it after instantiation. (But that will not work if you keep it `final`), or you set it in your constructor. So in your constructor you say `this.next = this`;

Comment: Depends on how tricky you want to go. I mean `Unsafe` exists, but IMO that actually goes outside of the scope of "possible in Java".

Comment: @f1sh don't you mean "you'd have to use reflection to change the field's value"? A simple `final` is no match for `.setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: @Kayaman I didn't know that. I thought `final` was a runtime thing too!

Comment: @f1sh I wasn't thinking of reflection, but of tricks similar to how you do recursive lambda functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25473855/205521

Comment: Why do you want to use complicated tricks, instead of just making the trivial change to the `Node` class?

Comment: @f1sh `final` is a runtime thing, but more complicated. Ordinary bytecode still may not write to a `final` field outside a constructor and `static final` fields are not allowed to be changed even via Reflection (letting off-specification hacks aside). The reflective modification of `final` instance field is allowed explicitly, to aid cloning and serialization code.

Comment: @Holger What change are you suggesting? Making the class not immutable? There is a host of reasons to who I prefer immutable classes.

Comment: Adding another special constructor that can assign `this` to `next`. Or to allow circles of arbitrary length: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995933/2711488