# Lazy graph structure caching and concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, java-memory-model

I am seeing some strange NPEs and have found out that this is a concurrency issue. I'm using code similar to the following:

```
class Manager {
  private final ConcurrentMap<String, Value> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public Value get(String key) {
    Value v = map.get(key);
    if (v == null) {
      new Value(key, this);
      v = map.get(key);
    }
    return v;
  }

  public void doIt(String key) {
    get(key).doIt();
  }

  void register(String key, Value v) {
    map.put(key, v);
  }
}

class Value {
  private final Value[] values;
  private final SubValue v;

  Value(String key, Manager m) {
    m.register(key, this);

    // Initialize some values, this is where a cycle can be introduced
    // This is just some sample code, the gist is, we call Manager.get
    this.vs = new Value[]{ m.get("some-other-key") };
    // Other code ...

    this.v = new SubValue(m);
  }

  public void doIt() {
    this.v.doIt(); // <--- NPE here. v is null sometimes
  }
}
```

When I call `Manager.doIt`, I sometimes get an NPE because `Value.v` is `null`. As far as I understand the happens-before relationships, it might be possible, that when `Manager.get` is called concurrently and when there is no entry yet for a key, that I can get back a not yet fully initialized Value.

I'm registering objects in the constructor of `Value` because the object graph between `Value` objects can have cycles and without this, I would get a stackoverflow exception.

The question now is, how do I ensure in `doIt` that the `Value` and all connected values are fully initialized? I'm thinking about doing some kind of double checked locking in `Manager.get` but I'm not sure how to solve this best. Something like this:

```
  public Value get(String key) {
    Value v = map.get(key);
    if (v == null) {
      synchronized(map) {
        v = map.get(key);
        if (v == null) {
          v = new Value(key, this);
        }
      }
    }
    return v;
  }
```

Has anyone a better idea about how to solve this or sees a concurrency issue with that code?

Comment: While I am still figuring out the rest of the program, double-checked locking suffers from memory visibility problems itself.

Comment: The problem here is not memory visibility. Inside V's constructor, you're making this reference escape even before the object is properly constructed.

Comment: as a side note, your entire _get_ method is not thread safe, by any means. Look into `computeIfAbsent` and carefully read it's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with is the following which is scalable and as far as I can tell, safe:

```
class Manager {
  private final ConcurrentMap<String, Value> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public Value get(String key) {
    Value v = map.get(key);
    if (v == null) {
      Map<String, Value> subMap = new HashMap<>();
      new Value(key, subMap);
      map.putAll(subMap);
      v = map.get(key);
    }
    return v;
  }

  public void doIt(String key) {
    get(key).doIt();
  }
}

class Value {
  private final Value[] values;
  private final SubValue v;

  Value(String key, Map<String, Value> subMap) {
    subMap.put(key, this);

    // Initialize some values, this is where a cycle can be introduced
    // This is just some sample code, the gist is, we call Manager.get
    this.vs = new Value[]{ subMap.containsKey("some-other-key") ? subMap.get("some-other-key") : m.get("some-other-key") };
    // Other code ...

    this.v = new SubValue(m);
  }

  public void doIt() {
    this.v.doIt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're making `this` escape in the constructor.

```
class Value {
  private final Value[] values;
  private final SubValue v;

  Value(String key, Manager m) {
    m.register(key, this); <--- (this is not properly constructed)

    // Initialize some values, this is where a cycle can be introduced
    // This is just some sample code, the gist is, we call Manager.get
    this.vs = new Value[]{ m.get("some-other-key") };
    // Other code ...

    this.v = new SubValue(m);
  }

  public void doIt() {
    this.v.doIt(); // <--- NPE here. v is null sometimes
  }
}
```

Now if some thread calls `doIt` on a key that has an improperly constructed object against it in the map, you might get an `NPE` as the `Subvalue` v for that object might not have been initialised.

The code has another issue. `Manager.get()` is a compound action, and should be encapsulated in a `synchronised` block. If one thread observes a `null` value for a key, by the time it enters the `if` block, that observation might become stale. Since the map is involved in the compound action, all methods that reference the map should be guarded by the same lock - basically you need to guard `get()` and `register()` with the same lock.

Comment: Since register is only ever called in the constructor of `Value` I think my solution should be safe, because the lock is only acquired when creating the `Value`, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it's not safe. Whey you call register, you're putting an improperly constructed object in the map. There is a race condition - another thread might do a get on that key, get the improperly constructed object, and dereference a field that has not been initialised yet. Making 'this' escape from the constructor is never a good practice, even when it's the last step in the constructor.

Comment: 1+, this is correct. @ChristianBeikov you can think about it rather easy: some thread reads `this` (whatever) you called `register` with _before_ the constructing thread does `this.v = new SubValue(m);` for example. And of course sees a `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it was a bit late yesterday :D

I can't move the register out of the constructor because otherwise I can't have a cyclic object graph. Maybe I should create an intermediate map (visible only to one thread) for initialization and after initialization put all objects in the shared map. What do you think? It's not a problem when some objects are created multiple times when initialized concurrently.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov the construction of the cyclic graph does not depend on the `register` method at all. There would be no difference if you just construct all objects of the cyclic graph first and traverse them afterwards to call `register` for each.

Comment: @Holger How would I do that? When `Value` constructs values directly instead of looking up an existing instance from the cache, i get a stack overflow A -> B -> A (recursion), the point is, I want `Value` to be immutable.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov when object `A` is constructed, it passes itself to the constructor of `B`. As simple as that. Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995933/2711488), for example. The `Manager` detour does not improve anything. Unless you consider exposing incomplete objects during construction an improvement.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov does this solve your problem? If yes, then please consider accepting it.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to use a lock on every access, so your answer is not entirely what I was looking for. I think the only "good" solution would be to have a isolated map and copy over all values after they are fully constructed. This might lead to some duplicate objects, but that's fine for me

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I think the answer pretty much points out the exact mistake that you made. Constructing a solution shouldn't be that difficult now.